# Material ui Date Picker show selected value -1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

```
 Material UI Date Picker show default value -1  for us time zone
 but show the correct date for Indian time zone
```

Relevant imports

---

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
```

My state default value

---

```
state = {
   coverDate: '2000-01-01',
}
```

### my Date picker

```
<DatePicker value={new Date(this.state.coverDate)}
            onChange={this.onCoverDateChange}
            formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} 
            disableYearSelection={false}/>
```

### onCoverDateChange method

```
onCoverDateChange = (event, date) => {
    console.log("coverDate value date to = " + date);
    this.setState({ coverDate: date });
}
```

when I select my computer time zone as Kolkata (India) 
        -- the default value shown by date picker is  2000-01-01

but

when I change my time zone to Montreal (US)
        -- the default value shown by date picker is  1999-12-31
                    It is a React project and I am using admin on rest.

Comment: have you solved it? please share! thanks!

Comment: Found any solution ?